# Calling start/stop letter environment inside luacode block

Tags: context, context-mkiv, letters

I'm creating a letter using the ConTeXt `letter` module, and I want to process an external file within Lua and change some of the letter setup and text based on the data in the external file. I'm confused about the correct way to use `context.startletter()`.

```
\usemodule[letter]

\startluacode

userdata = userdata or {}

function userdata.printLetter()
    context.startletter()
    context("Basic letter text")
    context.stopletter()
end

\stopluacode

\starttext

\ctxlua{userdata.printLetter()}

\stoptext
```

Compiling this trivial letter example yields an `undefined control sequence` for me.

EDIT: After some more tinkering, it seems that changing `context.stopletter()` to `tex.print("\\stopletter")` generates the letter that I expected.  I'm still confused about the mechanism causing the problem or *why* that change works.

Answer (score 2):

The letter environment uses a buffer to collect the content before it it adds the other elements (e.g. the opening). To use a buffer environment from Lua you have to use `context.delayed` instead of `context` in your code.

```
\usemodule[letter]

\startluacode

userdata = userdata or {}

function userdata.printLetter()
    context.delayed.startletter()
    context("Basic letter text")
    context.delayed.stopletter()
end

\stopluacode

\starttext

\ctxlua{userdata.printLetter()}

\stoptext
```

Comment: Adding `context.delayed` does produce an error-fee compilation of the file, but the resulting .pdf doesn't use any of the letter styling.  Is there additional work I need to do to feed the buffer to the letter environment?